# Yoshi's Wooly World and Wii Remote classic

Tags: wii-u, yoshis-woolly-world

I've just bought the game and I am unable to use the Wii remote as a playable controller.

The Wii Remote is properly synced with the Wii U (I am call the home menu and such), however on the controller selection screen, the Wii Remote is totally unresponsive.

I am very sad...

Did I miss anything?

Comment: Just to be clear, are you trying to use the Wii remote, or the Classic controller connected to a Wii remote?

Comment: The Wii Remote first generation.

Answer (score 1):

I had to tap the `2`, which seems terribly unintuitive.